# How to detect which version of the Az PowerShell module collection is installed on an Azure DevOps agent?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

On Azure DevOps agents there is no Az module collection installed - `Get-InstalledModule Az` returns `$null`. But all Az modules are just available - `Get-Module Az* -ListAvailable` returns them all.

What is the best way to test if a particular version of the Az module collection is available? Unfortunately the Az module itself is not present in the regular module space; it only appears in the list of installed modules if installed: `Get-Module Az -ListAvailable` always returns `$null`.

Just to be sure we always test whether a particular minimum version of the Az module collection is installed. And if not, then we install it. As this easily takes a couple of minutes to complete, ideally we only do it when really necessary.

Comment: As it's a collection of modules, you would have to individually assess them, or if Microsoft maintain the same version number for all of the individual Az modules, just against one of them (I can't check at the moment as I do not have them on this machine). You could easily loop through them though and check them against a version. `Get-Module Az* -ListAvailable | % { [version]"3.8" -ge $_.Version }`

Comment: You could even check against the available versions in the PowerShell Gallery.

Comment: You will be surprised that none of the separate Az modules have a version of 3.8 or higher ;-)

Comment: Wish there was a direct cmdlet for listing all Azure modules versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the [images of Microsoft-hosted agents](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/tree/master/images), for example, for Windows Server 2019 image, you can get Az PowerShell module from following link:

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#az-powershell-module

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Based on your answer I am thinking to just `Get-Module Az.Accounts` and inspect the path of this module. This will tell me the active version of the Az module collection. Interestingly, `Import-Module Az` works whereas `Get-Module Az` returns `$null`! Applying this work-around test saves a couple of minutes of unnecessary installing :-)

Answer (score 3):

We have investigated Microsoft's Azure PowerShell task, as this task's feature is to enable an Az version of choice or choose the latest available. The latter is done by the function `Get-LatestModule` in `Utility.ps1` which can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV5/Utility.ps1

Our full logic in the custom task is now capable of finding any installed version when running on a self-hosted agent or picking the latest on the Microsoft agent:

```
# On our self-hosted agent the Az module is installed
$installedVersion = (Get-InstalledModule -Name 'Az' -AllVersions -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Version | Sort-Object -Desc | Select-Object -First 1

if ('2.6.0' -gt $installedVersion) {
    # On Microsoft hosted agents the Az module itself is not present, but all the related Az modules are on disk in a specific folder
    # This code is taken from Microsoft Azure PowerShell task (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV5/Utility.ps1)
    $hostedAgentAzModulePath = Get-LatestModule -patternToMatch "^az_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$" -patternToExtract "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$"
    if (-not $hostedAgentAzModulePath) {
        # The hosted Az modules cannot be found. So proceed with installing it from the PowerShell gallery
        Write-Information -MessageData "INFO --- Install module 'Az'." -InformationAction Continue
        Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
        Install-Module -Name 'Az' -AllowClobber -Force -MinimumVersion '2.6.0' -Scope CurrentUser
    } else {
        # Append the Az modules path to the PowerShell modules path
        $env:PSModulePath = $hostedAgentAzModulePath + ";" + $env:PSModulePath
        $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath.TrimStart(';') 
    }
}

Import-Module -MinimumVersion '2.6.0' -Name 'Az' -Force -Scope 'Global'
Write-Information `
    -MessageData "INFO --- Imported Az module version $(Get-Module Az | Select-Object Version | ForEach-Object {$_.Version})." `
    -InformationAction Continue
```

`Get-LatestModule` copied from `Utility.ps1`:

```
function Get-LatestModule {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string] $patternToMatch,
          [string] $patternToExtract)
    
    $resultFolder = ""
    $regexToMatch = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex -ArgumentList $patternToMatch
    $regexToExtract = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex -ArgumentList $patternToExtract
    $maxVersion = [version] "0.0.0"
    $modulePath = $env:SystemDrive + "\Modules";

    try {
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $modulePath)) {
            return $resultFolder
        }

        $moduleFolders = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $modulePath | Where-Object { $regexToMatch.IsMatch($_.Name) }
        foreach ($moduleFolder in $moduleFolders) {
            $moduleVersion = [version] $($regexToExtract.Match($moduleFolder.Name).Groups[0].Value)
            if($moduleVersion -gt $maxVersion) {
                $modulePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($moduleFolder.FullName,"Az\$moduleVersion\Az.psm1")

                if(Test-Path -LiteralPath $modulePath -PathType Leaf) {
                    $maxVersion = $moduleVersion
                    $resultFolder = $moduleFolder.FullName
                } else {
                    Write-Verbose "A folder matching the module folder pattern was found at $($moduleFolder.FullName) but didn't contain a valid module file"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Verbose "Attempting to find the Latest Module Folder failed with the error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        $resultFolder = ""
    }
    Write-Verbose "Latest module folder detected: $resultFolder"
    return $resultFolder
}
```